# How to use a value in one function in another function

Tags: python

Pretty much I am trying to use the user inputs gotten in the sales function in the addVat function

```
Sales_Figures = []

def sales():
    num = int((input("Please enter sales figures: ")))
    Sales_Figures = [num]
    while num != -1:
        num = int(input("Please enter sales figures: "))
        Sales_Figures.append(num)

    print("The sales figures entered were:", end=" ")
    for num in Sales_Figures:
        if num != -1:
            print(num, end=", ")

    print("The sales figures including VAT are")
    return Sales_Figures

def addVat():

sales()
```

Comment: A key feature of functions is that they can take _arguments_. I suggest looking into some Python tutorials on functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the given code snippet is that you override Sales_Figures.
You can either remove the second line:

```
Sales_Figures = [num]
```

That is, define your method as follows (in this solution you don't need to return the list, as it is defined outside):

```
def sales():
    num = 0
    while num != -1:
        num = int(input("Please enter sales figures: "))
        Sales_Figures.append(num)

    print("The sales figures entered were:", end=" ")
    for num in Sales_Figures:
        if num != -1:
            print(num, end=", ")

    print("The sales figures including VAT are")
```

Alternatively you can define Sales_Figures inside the method and the return it:

```
def sales():
    num = 0
    Sales_Figures = []
    while num != -1:
        num = int(input("Please enter sales figures: "))
        Sales_Figures.append(num)

    print("The sales figures entered were:", end=" ")
    for num in Sales_Figures:
        if num != -1:
            print(num, end=", ")

    print("The sales figures including VAT are")
    return Sales_Figures
```

As you now invoke the method, use the return value

```
Sales_Figures = sales()
```

Finally,
    VAT_RATE = 1.05
    def addVat(s):
        return [VAT_RATE*x for x in s]

```
addVat(Sales_Figures)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put return parameter of `sales()` function in a variable and then  pass it to `addVat()`

```
Sales_Figures = []

def sales():
    while num != -1:
        num = int(input("Please enter sales figures: "))
        Sales_Figures.append(num)

    print("The sales figures entered were:", end=" ")
    for num in Sales_Figures:
        if num != -1:
            print(num, end=", ")

    print("The sales figures including VAT are")
    return Sales_Figures
saleFigures= sales()
def addVat(saleFigures):
```